# How to nest an expression in the iif true or false result (SSRS report)

Tags: vba, reporting-services

**This is my original expression :**

```
=replace(iif(Fields!AdresseMemeQueSiegeSocial.Value = "true", "Même que le siège de l'agence", Fields!AdresseComplete.Value), vbcrlf, "< br />")
```

**If it's false, i want to show the values of this expression (note: this is an expression for a similar field and it works) which is a 3 lines adress (sorry it's in french) :**

```
First(Fields!AdresseLigne1.Value, "FDPA_Agence_SiegeSocial")+ vbcrlf +
 First(Fields!AdresseLigne2.Value, "FDPA_Agence_SiegeSocial")+ vbcrlf +
 First(Fields!AdresseLigne3.Value, "FDPA_Agence_SiegeSocial")
```

**What i tried, thinking it would work, i played with parentheses, removed some fields, without success**

```
=replace(iif(Fields!AdresseMemeQueSiegeSocial.Value = "true", "Même que le siège de l'agence", (First(Fields!AdresseLigne1.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")+ vbcrlf +
 First(Fields!AdresseLigne2.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")+ vbcrlf +
 First(Fields!AdresseLigne3.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")), vbcrlf, "< br />")
```

**Error: no iif accepts this number of arguments**

**My question**

How can i make this expression fit in this expression ?

**Thanks a lot :)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression is missing the closing parenthesis for the IIF (or an unneeded parenthesis in front on the first First). Expressions are easier to read using indents and lines.

```
=replace(
    iif(Fields!AdresseMemeQueSiegeSocial.Value = "true", 
            "Même que le siège de l'agence", 
            (First(Fields!AdresseLigne1.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")+ vbcrlf +
             First(Fields!AdresseLigne2.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")+ vbcrlf +
             First(Fields!AdresseLigne3.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur")
             )
        ), 
    vbcrlf, "< br />")
```

The Address fields could be merged in one FIRST function:

```
=REPLACE(
    IIF(Fields!AdresseMemeQueSiegeSocial.Value = "true", 
            "Même que le siège de l'agence", 
            FIRST(Fields!AdresseLigne1.Value + VBCRLF +
                     Fields!AdresseLigne2.Value + VBCRLF +
                     Fields!AdresseLigne3.Value, "FDPA_Demandeur_AdresseDemandeur") 
        ), 
        VBCRLF, "< br />")
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot ! Btw the first one worked but not the second one :)